# Does "Flush Magento Cache" refresh all caches?

Tags: admin, cache, admin-panel

On the Cache Management page in Magento admin, does clicking the "Flush Magento Cache" button do the same thing as selecting all the check-boxes in the grid, choosing the Refresh action and clicking Submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is same as refreshing individual ones.

But sometimes you need to flush the entire cache storage or remove the `var/cache` directory to ensure all the cache is cleared if custom extensions are installed.

Comment: Also, since 1.4.x.x, there's quite a bit of stuff left in cache after the cache clear, so manually deleting the subfolders in var/cache to refresh some of the low level Zend functions that are cached sometimes is necessary.

Comment: Agreed. You can write your own controller in the admin backend to do so to ease the pain of deleting the folder manually on the server. The folder will be automatically next time the cache is generated if the recommended permissions for var directory are set.